# Quick comparison of folders - only bool as a result

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 folders with files on Windows:

- **Local folder** e.g C:\MyFolder
- **Network folder** e.g. \server\MyFolder

I need to check whether \server\MyFolder has got any updates in compare to my local one (e.g. updated file etc.).
I only need to know if there is any update in the network folder, I don't need to know what are the differences.

I tried implementing MD5 check sums on the folders, but this solution is too slow. Creating MD5 checksum on the network folder is just too slow (in my case 3-4 minutes, but I need this comparison to be made in max. few seconds) [we are talking about folders with few hundred files, and few hundred MB in size]

I tried implementing some basic rules (e.g. if number of files differs, names are different then it is a quick response), but in most of the cases number of files remain the same, and the only change is in the content of the file, so as long as the first files changes then it is quick response, but in the worst case scenario (or in the scenario that folders are the same) I end up iterating through all files, which is very slow (few minutes).

What other approaches could I try ?

(Note, that network drive is read only to me, so I can't store any information, checksums in the folder whenever it changes).

Comment: File modification date? (And/or file creation date, if files are replaced entirely.)

Comment: Maybe a [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-6.0), then you are notified immediately

Comment: Thanks- FileSystemWatcher is not an option, since application can be triggered on user's PC at any time.

Comment: the modification date that was suggested is a valid criteria. Consider that in linux there's a tool for that called rsync and that's the exact rule it uses to catch differences unless asked to do so via checksum. But you could also use file size to some extent.. but yet the modified date is more effective

Comment: I just approached Modification Date solution and unfortunately it is slow as well. 
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filename) <- this is quick
but as soon as I call "fi.LastWriteTime" it is slow, it takes few hundred milliseconds to get that property. Based on quick google, when I call LastWriteTime property it needs to instantiate a DirectoryInfo object using a UNC path, which is slow.

Comment: That may be one-time overhead, though. See if `DirectoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos` to retrieve everything from one directory at a time is better; I'd be surprised if it's proportionally slower. If that's too slow as well, you may be looking at an unsolvable problem, in the sense that doing things remotely won't ever be fast enough -- you need to somehow shift some processing to the server side if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution :
You loop your folder's file and everytime check this variable.
var lastModified = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime("Server/Folder");
if lastModified > the time of your code execution recurrence. then you should return the true or false

Comment: that date should be compared against the same filename found on the local folder not against the time of execution

Comment: Yes, and we can do that in the same for loop !